# How should I write case statement depend of parameters key?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

For example I have index action:

```
  def index
    if params[:query]
      @pharmaceutics = Pharmaceutic.where("name LIKE ?", params[:query])
    elsif params[:code]
      @pharmaceutics = Pharmaceutic.where("barcode LIKE ?", params[:code])
    else
      @pharmaceutics = Pharmaceutic.all
    end
  end
```

And when I send two params: code and query I would like to filter my Pharmaceutics using both of them. I have MySQL database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would probably use [`scoped`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods/scoped) method, like this:

```
def index
  scope = Pharmaceutic.scoped # Pharmaceutic.all if you use Rails 4
  scope = scope.where('name LIKE ?', params[:query]) if params[:query].present?
  scope = scope.where('barcode LIKE ?', params[:code]) if params[:code].present?
  @pharmaceutics = scope
end
```

You can also write your custom scopes and replace `where(...)` with them to make the code clearer.

Comment: @regedarek in Rails 4 you could use `Pharmaceutic.all`, according to this:
http://blog.remarkablelabs.com/2012/12/what-s-new-in-active-record-rails-4-countdown-to-2013